# There are some issues when we test hawq on our hadoop cluster

Tags: hadoop, hawq

1. The hawq ssh'port is default 22. How can I specify other port, such as 333, 222?
2. When we built pxf plugins(hdfs, service hbase, hive), I got itself rpm package, but when I rpm the pxf-service package, I got some errors:

   > Failed dependencies: hadoop >= 2.6.0 is needed by pxf-service-0:3.0.0-root.noarch hadoop-hdfs >= 2.6.0 is needed by pxf-service-0:3.0.0-root.noarch.

I build the pxf plugins on hadoop 2.6.0 in cdh 5.4.0.

I would appreciate some recommendations.

Comment: Curious about why you'd have the need or desire to test HAWQ on CDH...

Answer (score 0):

1. I don't know if you can change the port for gpssh.  I've never heard that request before.
2. Cloudera has chosen to not be part of [ODPi](http://www.odpi.org) so HAWQ and PXF do not work with their distribution.  Try Hortonworks instead.

Answer (score 0):

gpssh/hawq relies on the default ssh daemon.
check /etc/ssh/sshd_config for default port change.

This is not a hawq configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the default port that the ssh clients use by changing it it /etc/ssh/ssh_config.  I have tested it before and it does work with gpssh.